# slider inside google map info window

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

**Problem:** I'm trying to integrate a slider (carousel) inside an info window of google map.

**1. JQuery code for the slider:**

```
<head>
...
    <script src="js/jquery.anythingslider.js"></script>
    <script>
       // Set up Sliders
        // **************         
        $(function(){
            $('#mySlider').anythingSlider({
                mode                : 'f',   // fade mode - new in v1.8!
                resizeContents      : false, // If true, solitary images/objects in the panel will expand to fit the viewport
                expand              : true,
                navigationSize      : 3,     // Set this to the maximum number of visible navigation tabs; false to disable

                onSlideBegin: function(e,slider) {
                    // keep the current navigation tab in view
                    slider.navWindow( slider.targetPage );
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
  ...
 </head>
```

**2. Html code.** This is how would the slider work inside a regular html page:

```
 <div style="width:450px;height:150px;">        
    <ul id="mySlider">  <!-- id corresponds to id used in Jquery code  -->

       <li>
         Content of Slide 1
       </li>
       <li>
          Content of Slide 2
       </li>
       <li>
          Content of slide 3
       </li>

     </ul>
  </div>
```

Now, I don't have much experience with JavaScript so how do I make the jquery code accessible inside an info window. In other words where should I put he slider code?

**EDIT:** 
This is what I tried so far but no luck

```
(function() {  
// Defining variables that need to be available to some functions
var map, infoWindow;
window.onload = function() {
    // Creating a map
    var options = {
        zoom: 3,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.09, -95.71),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);
    // Adding a marker to the map
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(40.756054, -73.986951),
        map: map,
        title: 'Click me'
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {


        // add some content to userLi1 
        var userLi1 = '<li>Some awesome content for the 1st list item</li>';

        // add some content userLi2
        var userLi2 = '<li>Some awesome content for the 2nd list item</li>'


        // Check to see if an InfoWindow already exists
        if (!infoWindow) {
            infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        }


        // Setting the content of the InfoWindow to the detail map
        //infoWindow.setContent(detailDiv);

        infoWindow.setContent('<div style = "width:450px;height:150px;"><ul id="mySlider">' + userLi1 + userLi2 + '</ul></div>');

        // Opening the InfoWindow
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);   

    });

    // initiate slider here
    $('#mySlider').anythingSlider({
        mode                : 'f',   // fade mode - new in v1.8!
        resizeContents      : false, // If true, solitary images/objects in the panel will expand to fit the viewport
        expand              : true,
        navigationSize      : 3,     // Set this to the maximum number of visible navigation tabs; false to disable

        onSlideBegin: function(e,slider) {
            // keep the current navigation tab in view
            slider.navWindow( slider.targetPage );
        }
    });
};
})();
```

When I run the code, the Jquery doesn't get triggered at all.

**EDIT 2: SOLUTION** I solved the problem by using McMaster code and wrapping the relevant jquery code with

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function(){
 });
```

So this is the entire code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {   // runs jquery when document is ready

function initialize() {
    var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
    map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
        zoom: 3,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.09, -95.71),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "holding..."
    });

    // looks for map, when tiles are loaded, fire function addmarkers                 
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', addMarkers);

}

function addMarkers() {
    var lat =37.09;
    var lng = -95-71;
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(
        lat,
        lng);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        map: map
    });
    // add some content to userLi1
    var userLi1 = '<li>Some awesome content for the 1st list item</li>';

    // add some content userLi2
    var userLi2 = '<li>Some awesome content for the 2nd list item</li>'
    // set marker content
    marker.html = '<div style = "width:450px;height:150px;"><ul id="mySlider">' + userLi1 + userLi2 + '</ul></div>';
    // add listener
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(marker.html);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });

}

initialize();      
google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function(){
    // initiate slider here
    $('#mySlider').anythingSlider({
        mode                : 'f',   // fade mode - new in v1.8!
        resizeContents      : false, // If true, solitary images/objects in the panel will expand to fit the viewport
        expand              : true,
        navigationSize      : 3,     // Set this to the maximum number of visible navigation tabs; false to disable

        onSlideBegin: function(e,slider) {
            // keep the current navigation tab in view
            slider.navWindow( slider.targetPage );
        }
    });
}); 


});
```

Comment: +1 for the  google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function(){
 });

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are actually making a DOM element directly on the document

you would need to use something like this:

```
infoWindow.setContent('<div id="mySlider"><ul><li>' + userLi1 + '</li><li>' + userLi2 + '</li></ul></div>');
```

EDIT:

This is fully working script modified from one of my projects to fit your needs:

```
$(document).ready(function() {   // runs jquery when document is ready

     function initialize() {
            var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
            map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
                 zoom: 3,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.09, -95.71),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });
            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: "holding..."
            });

           // looks for map, when tiles are loaded, fire function addmarkers                 
            google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', addMarkers);

          }

          function addMarkers() {
                var lat =37.09;
                var lng = -95-71;
              var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(
                                                lat,
                                                lng);
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLng,
                map: map
              });
             // add some content to userLi1 
            var userLi1 = '<li>Some awesome content for the 1st list item</li>';

            // add some content userLi2
            var userLi2 = '<li>Some awesome content for the 2nd list item</li>'
              // set marker content
              marker.html = '<div style = "width:450px;height:150px;"><ul id="slider2">' + userLi1 + userLi2 + '</ul></div>';
             // add listener 
             google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    infowindow.setContent(marker.html);
                  infowindow.open(map, marker);
                });

          }

          initialize();      
          // initiate slider here
        $('#mySlider').anythingSlider({
            mode                : 'f',   // fade mode - new in v1.8!
            resizeContents      : false, // If true, solitary images/objects in the panel will expand to fit the viewport
            expand              : true,
            navigationSize      : 3,     // Set this to the maximum number of visible navigation tabs; false to disable

            onSlideBegin: function(e,slider) {
                // keep the current navigation tab in view
                slider.navWindow( slider.targetPage );
            }
        });

});​
```

Comment: thanks for your response, however when I use your method I get a list of [object HTMLLIElement] inside infoWindow. Also edited the post, I forgot to specify that the javascript code doesnt trigger the slider code at all.

Comment: If I put the $ sign before the function at the beginning the map doesn't load at all. Otherwise if I remove it I'm getting the same results as before: jquery doesn't load at all.

Comment: is there a live version i can take a look at? id like to see the issue in action. check out this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uvfNm/), i reorganized your code a bit.. i overlooked some common mistakes last time (`$(document).ready()`, and `$(window).load()`). what does your google map initiation script look like?

Comment: finally had some time so i have re-configured your entire jquery code and it is working for me so far (without actually having the slider plugin, but the syntax is correct).
check out this last [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r6cQB/)
sorry it took all day to get a solution.. full-time jobs ya know... :-/

Comment: first of all I really appreciate it you taking time to help me. Now when I run your code the mad isnt loading at all. Which version of jquery are you using, maybe thats the problem

Comment: no problem man, i like helping with script issues, its fun for me...

didnt even think about the jq version.. lemme check... 1.7.2..
here are my script src's:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

    `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=weather"></script>`

also make sure your map div id is correct and already the DOM: `<body><div id="map"></div></body>`

i gotta run for now.. ill check up on you in an hour or so once i get home.

Comment: I solved the problem by adding the slider code inside a listener with domready event. Thanks for your help, appreciate it.

Comment: im glad you figured it out, hari. id like to see your final product once you complete it. a slider in the infowindow is a great idea.

Comment: Sure here I uploaded the test code that I tried  https://dl.dropbox.com/u/68982385/site/index.html

Comment: @hari is there any chance of including the css, anythingslider.css as I'm a newb and got very confused following and I have the chrome developer console telling me this Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'anythingSlider' 

I believe this is in the css mentioned.

Comment: @darwindave when an object has no method it generally refers to a javascript method.. you will need the anythingslider plugin [found here](http://css-tricks.com/anythingslider-jquery-plugin/) that references the `anythingSlider` method to declare and initiate your slider.